# How to implement Oracle hints in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I just wanted to know is there any way to implement Oracle hints in hibernate?

In the net i found that using native sqlquery we can implement the oracle hints in hibernate.

in some forum, they said using projectionlist we can implement the oracle hints in hibernate.

But my question is through configuration in hbm file wether we can implement oracle hints in common?

is there any other possible way to implement oracle hints in hiberna

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hint per Entity and not per query, then you may use `@Subselect`:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select /*+NO_MERGE*/ * from view_blabla")
```

Otherwise I am afraid you have to use native SQL query.